# Problems with loading ILPanel in ILNumerics

Tags: c#, winforms, ilnumerics

I have two forms in my code. When I click a button in Form1, it shows the second form (Form2). There is an ILPanel in Form2. The first time that I click the button, Form2 is shown without any problem, but if I close Form2 and then click the button on Form1 again, I get the following error message when Form2 is re-shown. Does anybody know why this is happening? Thank you.

[image]

The code is very simple but here it is again

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f = new Form2();
        f.Show();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have exactly the same issue.

Comment: The only workaround that I have found is that I create a new form with an ILPanel inside and load the form when the main form loads and set its visibility to zero right away so the user cannot see it but it is always open. It solved the problem for me as one ILPanel is always open. I have not tried the latest version of ILNumerics though which may have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug. One workaround - of course - is to reuse the form. "Closing" the form would not unload it, but only hide it. Clicking on button1 would only create the form for the first time and Show() it otherwise. That way, the OpenGL context (which seems to cause the problem) is not re-created every time you click on button1.

You can file a bugreport at http://ilnumerics.net/mantis